# How to listen for camera events in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm building an App which basically runs in the background, which allows the user to share his photos instantly after taking the photo to his friends wall. Is there any possibility to listen for events delegated by another app lets say in this case default iOS Camera App.

Thanks in advance for the answers :)

Comment: what kind of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under iOS 8 there's a new observer you can register, to monitor the Photos library for changes: [here's the documentation for it](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014404-CH1-DontLinkElementID_11), the section that would be of interest is `registerChangeObserver`.

Comment: Thanks that did the job, is there any way to make it work on iOS 7 ?

Comment: It's an iOS8 only change, you might be able to find something to do with ALAssets but I can't say for certain. I just remember seeing that one reading the API changes over the beta period.

Comment: Let me dig into that, Thanks